# How to access internet from an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux that is in a VPC?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I created an EC2 instance(using Amazon Linux AMI) in our VPC and am trying to install 3rd party tools like Docker from the command line. I configured HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and NO_PROXY to route the outbound traffic to corporate proxy. I am still not able to download docker images etc.,

Are there any specific steps to be performed for Amazon Linux distribution to setup HTTP proxy for all the command line tools?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just have to make sure one thing other than proxy which is inbound ports and outbound ports. The ports which will be used by docker or SSH like service should be open.

Comment: Yes, inbound/outbound ports are open for HTTP/SSH traffic. Also, I tried the same settings on SuseLinux distribution and it works just fine. I am able to connect to docker hub and download images using HTTP proxy config.